# Where can I sell my Magic: The Gathering cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I played for quite a few years and have a ton of cards that I want to get rid of. I have a mix of all editions before 2007. 7th, 8th, etc...

So the question is where can I sell them effectively. And if it is better to just get all rares out, and then sell the rest as a lot at a common hobby store.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: There are a ton of modern cards that due to availability issues are worth a few buck. Do some research on the modern sets commons and uncommons. There is a good chunk of change to be had there.

Answer (score 20):

To get the most money for your cards, I recommend that you do the following:

1. Separate out any valuable rares -- anything worth more than a few dollars -- and sell them individually.
2. Sell the rest of them in bulk. Generally speaking, commons and uncommons only go for about $.01, unless they're especially valuable in one of the non-Standard formats.

As for *where* to sell them, you have basically three options.

1. Sell them to your local game store. This is probably the most convenient option, but be aware that the local store is likely to offer you less than you could get in other venues, and they're usually flooded with commons and may not agree to buy your old commons and uncommons at all.
2. Sell them yourself on eBay. This is what I did when I needed to get rid of a few thousand old commons, which I sold in a great big unsorted box. You'll probably get a higher average price per card this way, but you'll have to handle the hassle of shipping yourself. And be aware that big boxes of cards can be *heavy*, and therefore expensive to ship.
3. Sell them to an online game store that buys cards. This is probably the least attractive option, since they will usually only offer prices similar to those you get selling to a local store, but you still have to ship them.

Comment: As a caveat to this, anything going all the way back to the beginning of magic is going to have value, no matter what it is. Beta or even better Alpha is better to sell all individually.

Comment: As far as valuable commons go, a good example is Lightning Bolt, even the least valuable of those on tcgplayer.com is showing for $2.50

Answer (score 5):

Definitely take the rares out and sell those separately. People often are looking to buy rare's individually, so you'll get much better prices.

If you don't mind spending a bit more time on the issue, use your knowledge of the game to  sort the commons and uncommons into which seem to be better than average and which are just typical. Look up the prices for those that seem good or are otherwise unusual online and perhaps sell those separately.

As to where I'd definitely check your local game store first as you'll get to deal directly with someone who has plenty of experience with card prices. If the owner won't buy them, ask if you can post a small notice somewhere in the store that you are selling them and give a brief description of what you have. Get a bit of word of mouth working for you too buy telling any friends you have that play that you're looking to get rid of them.

Finally, if none of these work, try to sell them on Ebay or an MTG dealing site. :D

Answer (score 4):

there are a number of good websites where you can sell your cards.

- Star City Games (or for that matter, any singles website you care to pick, there are literally hundreds) will buy cards at a lower than market price, instantly, with minimal fuss
- ebay will help you sell your cards but takes a sizeable cut.
- Magic Card Market for europeans is a good peer to peer selling platform

remember though, its not just rares that can be worth money, there are commons and uncommons that are worth more than many rares. [wasteland](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=wasteland), an uncommon, is worth around $60. [Karakas](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karakas), another uncommon is worth around $100, and [mana drain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=mana%20drain), a third uncommon, is worth $172, there are also various commons, such as [Serum Visions](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Serum%20Visions) which is worth $3, or something like [sinkhole](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=sinkhole), a $30 common. It is very much worth, if you are looking to get the best price for your cards, going through and finding the cards that are worth money, a quick way to do this is to print out a website's buy list and use it as a cheat sheet for cards that are worth money, if its on the list, you may well want to sell it individually, and you should set it aside (for now) and check its actual retail value (often three or more times what the buylist price is). if its lower than you want to bother with (its well worth setting yourself a limit, e.g. anything worth less than $1) sell it as bulk.

once you have set aside the cards you want to sell yourself, pick your favourite avenue, the returns you get depend on the time you want to invest. Sell the rest either as bulk collections on ebay, or to a singles website as they will often buy bulk.

Answer (score 2):

If you're from northern Europe I really recommend the site www.svenskamagic.com. It's easy to create an auction and sell your cards, especially if they're of high value.

As others have said. Cards of low value are easiest sold in bulk. You'll probably earn both money and convenience that way.

Answer (score 2):

For UK players, I'd like to recommend [LilianaMarket.co.uk](https://lilianamarket.co.uk). It's like an eBay for Magic: The Gathering, a peer to peer platform. You can list the cards that you'd like to sell, and others can buy them from you. 
Mythics and rares are of course the most popular ones, but I'd suggest adding as many cards as possible: the wider your collection, the more likely buyers can find you. Likewise, the platform gives you a suggested price, but the more affordable you make them, the easier will be to get them sold.

Disclosure: I'm one of the creators of LilianaMarket.

Comment: Hi Gio. Please see [our advertising policy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), notably titled "How to not be a spammer". It appears you have direct association with that site. That's acceptable, but you *must* disclose your affiliation in your posts.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up - I've added a note to the answer.

Comment: I just recently used that site to buy some cards. Worked fine. Haven't sold any yet but will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your local community probably has a facebook group where things like this are brought and sold. As they are local they can be a great option as they might be able to pick them up in person instead of paying large amounts for shipping lots of cards.