# Can Uncommon Magic cards be sold individually for a profit?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Background: this was previously part of a longer question which has been edited into multiple smaller questions. I’ve already researched selling Magic cards, including reading through [How do I find out a fair price for my Magic the Gathering cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/how-do-i-find-out-a-fair-price-for-my-magic-the-gathering-cards) and [Where can I sell my Magic: The Gathering cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/where-can-i-sell-my-magic-the-gathering-cards), and am getting into finer detail.]

I've noticed on eBay that many Uncommons seem to be sold individually. Assuming I have the time and interest in doing this (I have both), does anyone have experience selling uncommons like this? Generally speaking, can you even sell them profitably or do you just end up selling them in bulk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some uncommon cards can sell individually, like [Path to Exile](http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/item/126325), [Skullclamp](http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/item/110381)(before banned). You can check eBay or website like [Card Kingdom](http://www.cardkingdom.com), [Magic Cards Info](http://magiccards.info/) and so on to track the price.